# Поиск QMainWindow в приложении

Tags: c++, qt

Внедряюсь/Инжектируюсь в стороннее Qt-приложение. Перебираю все QWidget, но не нахожу среди них QMainWindow. Объясните, пожалуйста, как найти это главное окно? И возможно ли добавить скажем QPushButton в существующее окно, в котором я не нахожу centralwidget.

P.S. Я новичок в Qt, поэтому могу писать некоторые глупости!

Comment: Класс QWidget наследуется от QMainWindow поэтому по факту вы работаете с QMainWindow ) И я , возможно, не верно понимаю, но, что мешает добавить кнопку в редакторе формы, туда куда вам нужно, это самый простой вариант как по мне,вариант с добавлением элементов из кода слегка сложнее, но сложностей не должен представлять

Comment: Ключевое слово также в этом вопросе "инжектируюсь". Я внедряюсь в сторонний процесс (приложение) и хочу добавить туда свою кнопку.

Comment: @ГалицкийОлег В таком случае поясните ваше "инжектируюсь" чтобы всем было понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Забудьте об инжектировании в Qt приложения, они не используют обычные оконные процедуры и классы, но делают всё самостоятельно. Называется это alien widgets, просвещение можно начать с [Native Widgets vs Alien Widgets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#native-widgets-vs-alien-widgets)

Comment: Здесь внедрение происходит при помощи dll, которая также написана на qt. Поэтому она становится родной для приложения и приложение охотно предоставляет все свои виджеты. Я могу считывать текст с кнопок, нажимать на них и т.д., но вот добавить свою кнопку пока не получается. К тому же, не могу понять, как они QLabel прячут в некоторых местах. Вроде должен получить их через QApplication::allWidgets(), но не выходит. ..

Comment: @ГалицкийОлег, тогда нужно обращаться к той dll, с помощью которой работаете, к её документации.